# javascript image onload has 0 width and 0 height

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading an image from the file system and then I want to resize the image. it works fine in all browsers except for IE (11). Problem is that the image is loaded, but the width and height are 0.

I am out of options so I am posting this question here.

This is the code

```
function getAsImage(readFile, chatboxtitle) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(readFile);
    reader.onload = addImg;

}

function addImg(imgsrc) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute("src", imgsrc.target.result);

    console.log(img);

    console.log(img.width + " "+img.height);

    ... a lot of cool stuff happens here but it doesn't work because width is 0

}
```

OK, so the console prints the image which is like

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABAAAAAH0CAYAAAHUIW ... and much more.. >
```

So the image IS there. All browsers work fine except IE.

I tried to play with setting some IMG properties like style, width but none work.

Note, I am not a hardcore JavaScript developer. Maybe I am missing something. Is the DOM element not found?

**UPDATE**

I tried the answer below yesterday and it was working. But I tried the solution today and it is not working anymore. Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt2mk7ct/4/) .
It is not working in IE11 on Windows7 but it is on IE11 on Windows8.

Comment: Did you try *img.setAttribute("style", "width:100px;height:100px");* ?

Comment: Appear to return `img` `width` and `height` at http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/xt2mk7ct/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird IE behaviour. It turns out that you need to set src using

```
img.src = src_goes_here
```

Not via `setAttribute`

```
(function(doc){
    doc.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile);

    function readFile(ev) {
        var file = this.files[0],
            reader;

        if(file) {
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = getSize
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    function getSize(ev) {
        var img = doc.createElement('IMG');
        img.src = this.result; //wors in IE11
        //img.setAttribute('src', this.result); //doesn't work

        console.log(img.width, img.height);
    }
}(document))
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/y85yfdtr/)

**UPD:** Some additional research shows that in order to make IE to calculate image sizes when you set src using `img.setAttribute` you need to actually attach the image to the document. For example

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

[Another Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/y85yfdtr/1/)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't notice the image wasn't attached to the DOM, I thought you could't get the dimensions of anything without attaching it to the DOM

Comment: Weird thing is you can if you set src property of the node. Not via  `setAttribute` method.

Comment: I tried it, it worked but now it doesn't anymore. seee the fiddle I added

Comment: Dude, still works for me. Reload browser or something.

Comment: OK, its working in IE11 on windows 8, but not in IE11 on windows 7

Comment: nice one, to add the image to the DOM but out of sight. it is working on WIN7 now :)